# Python Scrapy : allowed_domains adding new domains from database

Tags: screen-scraping, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to add more domains to allowed_domains , so I dnt get the " Filtered offsite request to ".

My app gets urls to fetch from a database, so I cant add them manually.

I tried to override the spider **init**

like this

```
 def __init__(self):
        super( CrawlSpider, self ).__init__()
        self.start_urls = []
        for destination in Phpbb.objects.filter(disable=False):
                self.start_urls.append(destination.forum_link)

            self.allowed_domains.append(destination.link)
```

start_urls was fine, this was my first issue to solve. but the allow_domains makes no affect.

I need to change some configuration in order to disable domain checking? I dont want this since I only want the ones from the database, but It could help me for now to disable domain check.

thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `'allowed_domains'` parameter is optional. To get started, you can skip it to disable domain filtering
- In `scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py` you can override this function for your custom domain filtering function :

  ```
  def get_host_regex(self, spider):
      """Override this method to implement a different offsite policy"""
      allowed_domains = getattr(spider, 'allowed_domains', None)
      if not allowed_domains:
          return re.compile('') # allow all by default
      domains = [d.replace('.', r'\.') for d in allowed_domains]
      regex = r'^(.*\.)?(%s)$' % '|'.join(domains)
      return re.compile(regex)
  ```