# scrapy allow all domains

Tags: python, scrapy

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320167/python-scrapy-allowed-domains-adding-new-domains-from-database) post to make scrapy crawl any site without allowed domains restriction.

Is there any better way of doing it, such as using a regular expression in allowed domains variable, like-

```
allowed_domains = ["*"]
```

I hope there is some other way than hacking into scrapy framework to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't set allowed_domains at all.

Look at the get_host_regex() function in this scrapy file:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py

Comment: Thanks. But, I want to set allowed_domains to all, is that possible?

Comment: If you don't set allowed_domains then all domains are allowed by default.

Comment: I have a class that extends scrapy spider and then another class that describes that one. So I have allowed domains in that intermediate class, but want to remove them from the final class

Answer (score 1):

you should diactivate offsite middlware which is a built in spider middleware in scrapy.
for more information http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html